# How do i access a local state inside the mapstatetoprops method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Thanks in advance.

Below is the snippet

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { itemReducer } = state;
  return {
    itemTree: getItemTree(itemReducer),
  };
};
```

`getItemTree` is a selector, and i would like to have another selector something like `getFilteredItemTree`.
This transition should based on a local state. How do i access a local state or variable in this function.
Or is there any other way to work on this.

Comment: You can access only component props. Check second param, [ownProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Comment: Local state of what exactly are you trying to access? mapStateToProps doesn't have its own state, and neither do selectors. Either this shouldn't be done, or you need to provide more context in case I do not understand you completely

Comment: this state have only values from reducers. If i try to destructure a local state for example. const { myLocalState } = state. it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can access props passed to this component through 2nd param of mapStateToProps but you can't access local state of the component. 
What you can do is pass the whole data in the component and then filter it in the component's lifecycle hook.